# chrome, type in search box, jumps up to address bar

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using Chrome. When I start to type in the search box in the middle of the screen, the cursor immediately jumps up to the address bar. I've tried disabling instant search (can't find the switch now).

It just started happening. I just to type in the search box in the middle of the screen.

I guess to be more clear, this is from the New tab screen.

Version 43.0.2357.130

Comment: Its a feature of google chrome to make the text and cursor jump from from search bar to the address bar. Both the search bar and the address bar have identical functionality in google chrome. How has this feature become a problem to you? Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

the reson why this is happening is might the update of google chrome.

Solution: learn to type from the address bar. both search box and the address bar act the same, so there isn't a *need* to actually search from the search box *specifically*.

(as it's also called, the address bar is called an omnibox, for handling both links and search. https://www.chromium.org/user-experience/omnibox)

(If this doesn't answer your question, please clarify on *why* you need to use the search box specifically.

Answer (score -1):

You can adjust Google Instant in the preferences pane:

http://www.google.com/preferences

Select to "Never show instant results" and then press "Save" at the bottom. Now when you search on Google.com, it will act like it used to

Comment: I have instant off, if i start chrome it's ok. but from the new tab window it still does it.

Comment: @jeff This is due to the way New Tabs are created within Google Chrome - They will bring you to a default google "blank" page. If you wish to change this, you will need an extension such as New Tab Redirect (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-redirect/icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna?hl=en) in order to change what page loads